# Cannot Access the Qt UI from an external cpp file

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Im trying to make a program an in that program I want to press a button that processes some text in another cpp file and appends my QTextEdit. I basically as a test just setup my button to run a function in the other file and also in when the program starts. When it starts it properly prints to the Text Edit as well as my console but when I press my button it only prints to the console and not to my TextEdit. For the function that appends the text in my TextEdit and prints to the console, I made it a public slot so I could access it from my other file.

This is my quiz.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "quiz.h"
#include "ui_quiz.h"
#include "test.h"

Quiz::Quiz(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::Quiz) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setText();
}

Quiz::~Quiz() {
    delete ui;
}

void Quiz::on_actionQuit_triggered() {
    QCoreApplication::quit();
}

void Quiz::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    run();
}

void Quiz::setText() {
    ui->console->append("Hello");
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

This is its header:

```
#ifndef QUIZ_H
#define QUIZ_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Quiz;
}

class Quiz : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Quiz(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Quiz();
public slots:
    void setText();
private slots:
    void on_actionQuit_triggered();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();
private:
    Ui::Quiz *ui;
};

#endif // QUIZ_H
```

This is my test.cpp:

```
#include "quiz.h"
#include "test.h"
#include "ui_quiz.h"

void run() {
    Quiz* quiz = new Quiz();
    quiz->setText();
}
```

and its header:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#endif // TEST_H

void run();
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can I not access the ui but the rest of the function runs?

Comment: You create a new instance of `Quiz` in the `run` function. It's not the same instance you show on the screen. Call `quiz->show()` in `run` so you will get an idea what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

you can access UI only from Main thread.
you can use signal-slot to do that. 
write your slot in main. and emit your signal from second class.
connect signal-slot in constructor main.

second class .h file:

```
void updateUI(QString str);
```

second class .cpp file:

```
emit updateUI("some text");
```

main class .h file:

```
void updateUI(QString str);
```

main class .cpp file(implementation):

```
void Main::updateUI(QString str)
{
    // change ui here
}
```

main class .cpp file (in constructor):

```
connect(secondobj, &secondclass::updateUI, this, &mainclass::updateUI);
```

Comment: I am using slots... does it have to be in main, not my gui?

Comment: How are you meant to use signals? where are they meant to be connected? the wiki is horrible

Comment: Whats the second object you referenced in the constructor

Comment: @Hamish make an object from second class.

Comment: no this isn't working its giving me this error- no matching member function for call to 'connect'

Comment: i test it on my computer. try this connect:
connect(secondClassObj, SIGNAL(updateUI(QString)), this, SLOT(updateUI(QString)));

Comment: @Hamish if my answer was helpful for you accept the answer or upvote it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In header file of your cpp where you want to use the UI, add the following lines of ui.

##.h file:

```
class A
{    
 Public:    
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
}
```

##.cpp file:

```
ui->label->setText(ui->button->text());
```